# Finding Transfer Response (Simplifying resistor circuit)

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to simplify the circuit shown in the image below, but i am not sure what to do with the resistor R3, as it is parallel to R2 but both are somehow connected to R4 (and so to ground).

[image: Circuit]

How are the resistors connected (in series and parallel) so that I can find a transfer function?

Comment: Look up Delta-Wye conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three ways:

1. Use the general node voltage method and solve the voltage over RL.
2. Find the Thevenin equivalent for V1, R1, R2, R3 and R4. It's what RL sees. Then you get easily the voltage over RL by using the voltage divider equation.
3. You can remove one resistor if you transform R1,R2,R3 from delta to Y. R4 can be combined with the mid branch of the Y. The rest can be solved using series and parallel resistors equations and the voltage divider equation.

3 does not shorten the calculations. I would try 2 at first if the transfer function from V1 to the voltage over RL was the actually wanted thing.

Method 1 is the brute force way. You can form two equations having the voltages over R4 and RL as the unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical exercise in which the extra-element theorem or [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) forged by Dr. Middlebrook excels. The principle is the following: identify an element in a circuit which, to your opinion, complicates the analysis. Remove it or replace it by a short circuit and calculate the transfer function this way, this is \$H_{ref}\$, the reference value. Then, reduce the excitation to 0 (your input source which reduced to 0 V is a short circuit) and calculate the resistance "seen" from the extra-element connecting terminals. This is \$R_d\$. Then, bring the excitation in place and calculate the resistance "seen" from the extra-element connecting terminals while the response is 0 V. You have \$R_n\$.

Let's see how we could apply this technique to your circuit. Here, we consider \$R_2\$ as the extra element. I make it a short circuit for my reference value. It is easy, if \$R_2\$ is a short, I have no attenuation therefore \$H_{ref}\$ is 1. Then, I reduced the excitation to 0 V and replace \$V_1\$ by a short circuit. The steps are shown in the below sketch:

[image]

At first glance, the resistive arrangement looks a bit weird. The key is to rearrange it in a friendlier form as I did. If you correctly inspect the sketch I have redrawn, you have \$R_d=R_L||(R_3+R_1||R_4)\$

For \$R_n\$, you have to think of the op amp virtual ground. Bring \$V_1\$ back in place and determine the resistance "looking" into \$R_2\$'s connecting terminals while \$V_{out}\$ is a null. This last statement is important, it is not a short circuit but rather, you consider that 0 current circulates in \$R_L\$ and the right side of \$R_2\$ is at 0 V. Like an op amp virtual ground. To determine this value, install a test generator \$I_T\$ and determine the voltage \$V_T\$ across its terminals. If you do the math ok (2 lines), you get \$R_n=R_3+\frac{R_1(R_3+R_4)}{R_4}\$. Applying the EET, you obtain the transfer function you want:

\$H=H_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_2}{R_n}}{1+\frac{R_2}{R_d}}=\frac{1+\frac{R_2}{R_3+\frac{R_1(R_3+R_4)}{R_4}}}{1+\frac{R_2}{R_L||(R_3+R_1||R_4)}}\$

This is a so-called *low-entropy* formula because all terms appear in a well-ordered form in a series-parallel arrangement. The below Mathcad sheet shows the results:

[image]

Now, I could have considered \$R_2\$ as open-circuited rather than a short. In this case, the reference function becomes \$H_{ref}=\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_1}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_3+R_1||R_4}\$ and the new EET formula is

\$H=H_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_n}{R_2}}{1+\frac{R_d}{R_2}}=\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_1}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_3+R_1||R_4}\frac{1+\frac{R_3+\frac{R_1(R_3+R_4)}{R_4}}{R_2}}{1+\frac{R_L||(R_3+R_1||R_4)}{R_2}}\$

The two formulas are identical as confirmed by Mathcad. Now the icing on the cake: replace \$R_2\$ by an inductor \$sL_1\$ in the first expression and you have the transfer function showing the pole and the zero. Use a cap. instead and replace \$R_2\$ by \$\frac{1}{sC_1}\$ in the second formula and you have the complete transfer function. The fast analytical circuits techniques are truly efficient in determining transfer functions. An introduction to these FACTs is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371).